# Get SmartGWT Canvas as HTML

Tags: html, gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to make a one-to-one copy of a SmartGWT canvas as HTML.  When I call .toString, I see a number of fields, such as position and background color.  What I need is some way to convert that into an HTML String, with tags that implement those same fields.

My approaches have included .getPrintHTML(...), .getContents(), and .getInnerHTML().  None have outputted this information.  I'm lost on this, and the internet is not being helpful.

*Is* there are SmartGWT way to do this?  Or, am I stuck trying to parse out the individual properties "manually"?

Help?

Comment: What's wrong with copying the DOM from Firebug / Chrome DevTools?

Comment: It's not a matter of debugging; the HTML needs to be saved algorithmically.  my_canvas.getDOM() seems to return null?

Comment: The internet is probably not helpful because this is a very strange use case... you might have to use GWT-JSNI. I don't know why on earth you would want to do this, but I would re-evaluate whatever decisions led you here.